# Retrofit is unable to create call adapter

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

This is my UserService Interface

```
 @GET(Constants.Api.URL_LOGIN)
    String loginUser(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String pass, @Field("secret") String secret, @Field("device_id") String deviceid, @Field("pub_key") String pubkey, @Field("device_name") String devicename);
```

In the activity I am calling

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.Api.URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
service = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
String status = service.loginUser(loginedt.getText().toString(), passwordedt.getText().toString(), secret, device_id, pub_key, device_name);
```

This creates an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.String
    for method UserService.loginUser
```

What am I doing wrong?

Gradle :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have included `addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())`, you are looking to use `Observable`'s to manage your calls.  In your interface, explicitly give the parameterized `Observable` instead of a `Call` --

```
@GET(Constants.Api.URL_LOGIN)
    Observable<String> loginUser(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String pass, @Field("secret") String secret, @Field("device_id") String deviceid, @Field("pub_key") String pubkey, @Field("device_name") String devicename);
```

and then your `service` methods create observables for you that you can subscribe to or use as the start of an observable pipeline.

```
Observable<String> status = service.loginUser(loginedt.getText().toString(), passwordedt.getText().toString(), secret, device_id, pub_key, device_name);
status.subscribe(/* onNext, onError, onComplete handlers */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Aleksei, if you need the most simple solution to get String result from Retrofit library, than you have to do this several calls:

1. At first, Gradle dependecies:

   ```
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0-beta4'
   ```
2. Your modified UserService Interface

   ```
   @GET(Constants.Api.URL_LOGIN)
   Call< String> loginUser(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String pass, @Field("secret") String secret, @Field("device_id") String deviceid, @Field("pub_key") String pubkey, @Field("device_name") String devicename);
   ```
3. Service client creation code:

   ```
   static UserService SERVICE_INSTANCE = (new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(Constants.Api.URL_BASE)
           .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
           .build()).create(UserService.class);
   ```
4. Calling the request:

   ```
   SERVICE_INSTANCE.loginUser(*all your params*).execute().body();
   ```

I hope, the solution is clear and shows simple String receive approach. If you need some another data parser, please, take a look at the conversters list here [Retrofit CONVERTERS](http://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration).